# Do multiple pieces of chameleon armour stack?

Tags: fallout-4

If I equip multiple pieces of chameleon legendary armour, will they have a greater effect than just a single piece?

Comment: @kalina I found a video to back up your answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRyqV2KuBTc  please undelete it so I can upvote :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes... wearing multiple pieces of chameleon armor will stack and give you a greater benefit. Here is a video that shows that:

Answer (score 8):

#### Yes - legendary item effects stack across multiple pieces of armor.

[As discussed here on the Fallout Wikia page for Legendary Armor Effects](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_armor_effects) (my emphasis):

> Legendary effects can be added to items by dropping them on the ground and using the console command "attachmod" while having them selected, followed by the mod ID. You can't stack several mods on a single item, **but you can stack over multiple pieces (armor).** You can also replace a mod with another one via console.

This means that if you have multiple pieces of armor with the same legendary effect, these will stack together.

Comment: In this particular case though he is asking if having multiple chameleon pieces provide any additional benefit in terms of stealth

Comment: To which the answer is "yes, legendary item effects [including chameleon] will stack across multiple pieces of armor"... ???

Comment: The chameleon effect gives you a stealth boy effect while crouching and not moving.  What would having two pieces buy you?

Comment: Chameleon does the following: "Enemies have a harder time detecting you while you're sneaking and not moving" - this is something that can stack since you can have a harder time detecting something.

Comment: I think this depends whether or not you get a 'stronger' stealth field effect when wearing multiple pieces of chameleon armor I don't think it's as cut and dry as the rest of the legendaries

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment because I have less than 50 rep so I have to post an answer.

Each piece that has chameleon confers a +20 bonus to stealth. With 5 pieces you get a total of +100 to your ability to remain hidden.

**More information:**

The Chameleon armor effect (ench_mod_LegendaryArmor_Chameleon) has a magnitude of 20 in the creation kit.

Through testing today I can personally confirm that multiple pieces being equipped in succession can increase your ability to remain hidden and even go from the Danger to Caution state and back as they are equipped and unequipped.

Comment: If you could elaborate (official verifiable source where you got those numbers from would be perfect) that would be a great answer

Comment: I couldn't find an official source, but through testing for about an hour today I saw a dramatic difference in rate of detection.

Answer (score 0):

I've only found 2 chameleon gears so far. A right and a left foot, so I was able to test them together. The visual distortion on the pipboy is compounded with multiple chameleons, making it very hard to read. 2 of them doesn't seem to provide a better avoidance of detection, other's have said each gives you "20" but what exactly the difference between 20 and 100 is is anybody's guess, but when combining the two with a stealth boy you're basically undetectable where 1+the stealthboy just feels like using a stealthboy, they'll see you and shoot you as if you aren't even using it, so however much a stealth boy provides + 2 chameleons seems to be the line of actual stealth if that makes sense? But what it definitely does do is give you some freedom to move very short distances, I think because the game for some reason can't activate or deactivate both gears effect simultaneous for some reason, you'll always hear a doubled sound effect when they trigger or deactivate. As a result, if you move and stop before the second or further gear deactivates, it won't. So there is a benefit, though it would require some skill and a decent controller to actually use it.

Bonus: narratively speaking the chameleon gear is one of the fewest legendary effects that actually makes sense. You have to understand that what you see it in your inventory and your character wearing are representative. Not all leather, metal, or raider armor are going to look the same because they are custom built by craftsman of varying skill with varying tools and materials. Next consider the fact that when you use a stealth-boy the burnt out stealth-boy isn't added to your inventory as a junk item, which it should be given the very rare and useful components that would be inside of it even damaged, there's certainly going to be gold, a circuit board, and nuclear material to say the least. But you don't keep it. Why? Presumably there's some reason, perhaps they become unbearably hot the longer they operate and when they burn out they literally BURN out and your character simply chucks it. Whatever the reason, the stealth-boy still exists somewhere on the ground for a raider to salvage, strip the components from, and strap onto a piece of armor with an improvised power supply that probably sucks ass compared to the original. Bam, chameleon gear.

Comment: It's a little hard to read given the excess color commentary/opinion, but I think you're saying that all the other answers which say the effects stack, plus the evidence they provide, are wrong. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Is this bonus section actually needed? This site is not a blog or any of the sort. ... And I believe "*but when combining the two with a stealth boy you're basically undetectable where 1+the stealthboy just feels like using a stealthboy, they'll see you and shoot you as if you aren't even using it, so however much a stealth boy provides + 2 chameleons seems to be the line of actual stealth if that makes sense?*" this part is the key; which is saying that the other answers are (technically) correct. This is basically: 1 chameleon + stealth boy is not enough, but 2 and stealth boy is. I guess.